# Polling for a certain change in Json Response in Java

Tags: java

I have a `Json` response from a `GET` request as below

```
{
   status: success
   requestCount: 10
}
```

I need to periodically do a `HTTP GET` and check if the `requestCount` is greater than 0. What would be the best  way to do this using `Java`? I tried using `Thread.sleep(2000)` but don't really know if that's the right way to do.

EDIT: If the `requestCount` is greater than 0 then perform some actions by calling other methods

EDIT2: I used `Thread.sleep(2000)` to periodically do a `GET` and check the response every 2 seconds. Then if `requestCount` is `>` 0, I perform some functions and get back to polling mode again

Comment: that sleep will determine how stale you allow your data to be so the real thing to consider is how stale should you allow your data to be? if this were the stock exchange 2 seconds is extremely old. how important is it for your data, during the sleep, it to be up-to-date?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz: Data is not very sensitive with respect to time. It can wait for quite some time (May be less than a minute). Real time change notification is not a requirement

Comment: then the next thing to consider is how much overhead is needed when requesting the data? if the overhead is small then you can ramp up your polling speed if need be. basically consider two things when polling, how much resources are needed to ask the question and how important your data is? Seeing is how you mention the data isn't very time sensitive i'd say 2 seconds is plenty as long as the overhead is small. However polling is not always ideal and you might want to consider the interupt methodology.

Comment: I agree. Overhead is small. polling may not be ideal here. I'd like to understand what other options can be used.

Comment: a simple interrupt would be to have your server (the one providing the JSON) send the JSON object once requestCount > 0 and have your client simply listen. That way you receive the data when the server is ready to provide it and don't have to keep trying GET over and over